# Registra el User pero no asigna al Customer

Tags: python, django

Estoy creando un ecommerce desde un tutorial. Todo corre bien, registro a un nuevo usuario con mi formulario, lo agrega sin problemas, pero al hacer Login me da el siguiente error:

`User has no customer.`

Al entrar al admin, veo que se creo el nuevo usuario pero cuando voy a Customers, no esta asignado, tengo que darle a agregar customer y asignarle el nuevo usuario. Y desde allí puede dar Login sin problemas ¿Cómo hacer que el nuevo usuario sea un customer?

```
class Customer(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
date_orderd = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

Mi formulario de registro es este:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Comment: Puede ser porque para tu modelo de registro estas usando el usuario por defecto de Django que es User, deberias usar tu modelo Customer